# Should I use was or were: It _ the eyes

Tags: difference, past-tense, singular-vs-plural, auxiliary-verbs, be-verb

The whole sentence is : it wasn't the face that scared me, it _ the eyes. What do I use in the blank?

Comment: The syntactic *subject* of your text is the "existential **it**", which is always ***singular***. So whatever "it" was, the verb itself is ***was***, not ***were***.

Answer (score 0):

### It’s always “was” with “it”

That’s because the pronoun “it” only ever replaces a singular noun; and “was” goes with [singular](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/to-be/) things. If we need a pronoun to replace multiple things you use “they” in the subject case and “them” in the object case. Noting that these can also be used of multiple people but it’s extremely rude to use it to refer to a singular person.

“It” here is replacing the thing that did the scaring. Not the face, the eyes.

But, wasn’t the thing doing the scaring the eyes, and don’t faces usually have two of them? Well, English can be tricky when referring to collections or sets of things - you can refer to the set as a singular whole “the eyes”, or its just as valid to refer to the individual members “those eyes”. So there are two legitimate ways of constructing your sentence:

1. It wasn't the face that scared me, it was the eyes.
2. It wasn't the face that scared me, that was those eyes.

If there was more than one face, you could also go with: it wasn't those faces that scared me, it was those eyes.

The choice is up to the speaker/writer, but the first sentence has a better feel because it is keeping the same number of things throughout: one person me, one face, one (pair of) eyes and it is more impactful due to the repetition of “it”.

Comment: "It" doesn't replace the singular "scared". "Scared" is a past participle used adjectivally, for which singular/plural is not a relevant attribute. "It" is a ***dummy subject***, as in ***it's raining***. Which remains singular even in contexts like ***It's raining in France and Germany*** (***They're** raining in France and Germany* is invalid).

Comment: **If it were** that simple "always", I wouldn't be leaving this comment.

Comment: Consider _It's my parents!_ "Parents" is definitely plural. The dummy subject "it" is singular and so is the verb. _They are my parents_ is grammatical but has a different meaning: it is (notionally) pointing to something (or rather, some people) and identifying them. _It is_ is a presentative, introducing "my parents" to the discourse, but not designating anything.

Answer (score 0):

In agreement with the previous answers, the missing word here should be 'was'. Another way to think about it is by reading back over the sentence, and noticing what verbs are used in the earlier part of the sentence:

> it **wasn't** the face that scared me, it _ the eyes

Wasn't is short for 'was not', so expanding the contraction, you can see 'it was not' used earlier in the sentence. Reversing this negative gives you 'it was', which goes in the second half of the sentence